# ruby model naming conventions can uppercase characters be used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have run a migration and am getting a 500 error saying `seen_by_hw` does not exist. Could this be due to the fact I have used an uppercase characters when creating the ruby model. eg
`seen_by_HW`. Or should it be `seen_by_hw`
thanks

Comment: https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices

Comment: this a good resource thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I just realized I posted the wrong link. I meant to do https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide. His https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide is very good, too.

Comment: This is another good resource to help with best practices. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created the model file/class yourself then yes, this is probably the issue.

The filename should be: `seen_by_hw.rb` and in that the class name will be `SeenByHw`.

If you use the generators that comes with Rails then it would have done this for you, type `rails generate` in your app directory to see more info on them.

Comment: Yes this was the issue.